# Why delete HPA of a stateful set in Kubernetes results in the pod number scaled to 0?

Tags: kubernetes

When I delete Horizontal Pod Autoscaler of my stateful set, the number of pod will drop to 0 for a short time and then rescale up to the original replica number specified in stateful.

Is it supposed to happen? If so, how could I prevent the number of pod drop to 0 when HPA deleted/crashed/or anything happened?